# Action Iterator

Tags: c#, delegates, iterator

How would I create an iterator of delegate "actions". Where I could feed the sequence into a foreach loop and complete each action before continuing with the next.

Is it possible to support multiple yields in the delegate "action" as well?

```
    public void SequenceTest()
    {
        List<Func<IEnumerator>> sequence = new List<Func<IEnumerator>> { () => Do(1), () => Do(2), () => Do(3) };

        Play (sequence);
    }

    private IEnumerator Play (IList<Func<IEnumerator>> sequence)
    {
        foreach (Func<IEnumerator> act in sequence)
        {
            yield return act();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Do(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Starting " + num);

        Console.WriteLine ("step A");
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".");
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("Ending " + num);

        yield return null;
    }

    private IEnumerator DoMulti(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Starting " + num);

        Console.WriteLine ("step A");
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("v");
        }
        yield return null;


        Console.WriteLine ("step B");
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".");
        }

        Console.WriteLine ("Ending " + num);

        yield break;
    }
```

Comment: So basically a pipeline of sorts?

Comment: functionally yes, but its also to further my own knowledge of iterators, yields and IEnumerators/IEnumerables.

Comment: State machines are a pretty common abstraction in software.  And yes, the *yield* keyword helps you implement them.  However, the notion that a state machine is *always* sequential, even when they are nested, will make your code hit the wall at about 100 miles an hour.  It can't avoid it, no way to steer left or right.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be achieved with a simple extension method...

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    numbers.Each(Console.WriteLine);
}

public static class Extensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var element in enumerable)
        {
            action.Invoke(element);
        }

        return enumerable;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as `IEnumerable.ForEach`, isn't it?

Comment: List.ForEach* IEnumerable has no ForEach extension

Comment: No worries, I found it rather odd as well when I realized that it wasn't implemented in IEnumerable, it's what would make most sense at least.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not really wanting to perform a single action on a sequence, but a sequence of actions. Also I'm trying to make it work with yield/IEnumerator.

Comment: The word ___sequence___ is making me wonder whether you mean a collection or an ordered sequence... if just a collection you can still adapt the code above, if you mean an ordered sequence, it would help to hear what you're attempting to achieve in the grand scheme of things